# Show Weak Topology on a Banach Space is Locally Convex

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am trying to show that the weak topology on a Banach space $X$ is locally convex.

I have some doubts on how to show addition is (weakly) continuous, i.e. $f:X\times X\to X$, $f(x,y)=x+y$ is (weakly) continuous.

**1)** Is it sufficient to show $f$ is weakly sequentially continuous? I.e. if $(x_n,y_n)$ converges weakly to $(x,y)$, then $f(x_n,y_n)$ converges weakly to $f(x,y)$?

Or do we have to show:

**2)** Preimage of open set (or subbasis) in $X$ is open in $X\times X$ under weak topology.

It seems to me that (1) is easier to show, but I am not sure if it is sufficient.

Comment: Show that the weak topology is generated by the system of semi-norms $p_E$ where $E\subseteq X'$ is finite and $p_E(x)=\max\lbrace|\varphi(x)|: \varphi\in E\rbrace$.

Comment: No, abstractly it is not enough to prove sequential continuity.  But if you know about nets (or filters), then you can prove actual continuity using the same insights as you would use to prove sequential continuity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x_0, y_0$ be two points of $X$ and $s_0 = x_0+y_0$. Let $W$ be a weak neighbourhood of $s_0$. It is enough to show that there are $U,V$ weak neighbourhoods of $x_0, y_0$ such that $U+V \subset W$. Its is even enough to show that for basis of neighbourhoods. If $W$ is of the form $$W =\{x \in X : |\langle f_i,x-s_0 \rangle| < \epsilon \quad \forall i \in I\},$$ where $I$ is finite, $f_i \in X'$ and $\epsilon >0$, then set $$U =\{x \in X : |\langle f_i,x-x_0 \rangle| < \epsilon /2 \quad \forall i \in I\}$$ and $$V =\{x \in X : |\langle f_i,x-y_0 \rangle| < \epsilon /2 \quad \forall i \in I\}.$$ Indeed, let $(x,y) \in U \times V$. For all $i \in I$ one has $$ |\langle f_i,(x+y)-s_0 \rangle| = |\langle f_i,(x+y)-(x_0+y_0) \rangle| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon,$$ which means that $(x,y) \in W$.